# Can't retrieve any content from Ajax-loaded page

Tags: ajax

Once `my_file.php` is loaded through Ajax I can't get any WordPress content from it, even though Wordpress functions run without generating any error messages. Note that I'm doing Ajax the old school way (the new regular way to do Ajax with WordPress is too complex for me).

JS:

```
var root_path;
var host_address = document.location.hostname;              
if (host_address == '127.0.0.1') { 
    root_path = 'http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/my_project';
    var local_server = 1; 
}
else {
    root_path = host_address;   
    var local_server = '';  
}   
var x = 'wp-content/themes/my_project/my_file.php';
if (local_server == 1) x = root_path + '/' + x;             
else x = 'http://' + root_path + '/' + x;   

$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: x,
    data: $(this).serialize(),      
    success: function(msg){
        $( '.container' ).html(msg);
    }
});
```

Then in my_file.php:

```
require_once( "../../../wp-config.php" );
```

... which gives me access to WP functionality. After that, get_categories() returns nothing but "uncategorized" and  query_posts() returns nothing at all (the exact same calls return plenty of categories and posts from non Ajax pages)

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'parent' => 0
);
$categories = get_categories( $args ); 

//

query_posts(array ( 'posts_per_page' => -1 ));
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;
```

Comment: Any errors with WP_DEBUG enabled? PS but really _really_ I would recommend to invest a bit of time into not-that-new-anymore Ajax in WP core. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is to just do AJAX the right way.

Enqueue your script and localize it to add the path to `admin-ajax.php`:

```
function wpd209588(){
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'wpd209588_script',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/your-script.js?ver=1.0',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
    wp_localize_script(
        'wpd209588_script',
        'WPaAjax',
        array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpd209588_scripts' );
```

In `your-script.js`, do your AJAX call:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $.post(
        WPaAjax.ajaxurl,
        {
            action : 'wpd209588_ajax'
        },
        function( response ){
            $( '.container' ).html( response );
        }
    );
});
```

Map your AJAX handler to the action you call in your AJAX script:

```
function wpd209588_ajax_function(){
    global $wp_query;
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        echo '<li>';
        the_title();
        echo '</li>';
    endwhile;
    exit;
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpd209588_ajax', 'wpd209588_ajax_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wpd209588_ajax', 'wpd209588_ajax_function' );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You just made me switch to the right way and for good :) So nowadays the code of the pages loaded through Ajax isn't stored any longer in separate files but are all in functions.php?